# Is it still valid to use Android AGPS to find current location?

Tags: android, gps, location, cellid

Is it still valid(meaning, rely on, though developer.android.com doesnt mentions it) to use
AGPS aka find location based on CellID.

http://www.anddev.org/poor_mans_gps_-_celltowerid_-_location_area_code_-lookup-t257.html

Also, I noted that to get Location address via CellID, requires an internet connection to hit a secret Google API. 
My requirement is simple, get latest/current location of the android device. Suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AGPS is not location based on cellID.

AGPS means downloading the GPS Satellite ephermides much faster from Internet than to download them from the satellites itself.

cellID locationing is an alternate locating technology, it  is not AGPS.

(It is never valid to use an secret Google API, the servcie may stop from one day to the other, leaving your App disfunctional)